# SWT: FontDialog without color selector

Tags: fonts, swt

How to show the SWT `FontDialog` without the color option (in our application colors are configured independent of the font)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse bug 35890](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35890) discusses this option, and it is labelled as fixed.

There is a new method :

```
 fontDialog.setEffectsVisible(false);
```

but when I try to use it on a Mac this is reporting

```
 cannot find symbol method setEffectsVisible(boolean)
```

and will not compile.  Windows only?  Maybe?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that dialog depends on system, on my win7 is default dialog `FontDialog dlg = new FontDialog(shell, SWT.NONE); dlg.open();` do contains color selection, but on Linux (Mint 1) does not..

So that's not best way, but you can just ignore the color selection you get from user in this dialog..

[image: win7]  [image: Linux mint]

Comment: We've created our own font chooser now. Because of this major usability problem SWT's one is no option for us.