# SWT Font Dialog Filtering

Tags: java, swt

I need to create a SWT Font Chooser dialog that display only those fonts that are monospaced. I know, more or less, how to check if a given font is monospaced or not, but I don't how to filter the list of fonts displayed. Does the FontDialog provided any hook method where I can access the list of availables fonts and apply a filter?

Comment: The `FontDialog` is the system default for choosing a font. Unfortunately, you can't influence which fonts are shown. You'll have to implement your own dialog :/

Comment: Apparently the OP of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493689/swt-fontdialog-without-color-selector) question has implemented a custom font chooser. Might be worth getting in contact with him and ask for a copy.